# Why I lose reputation when I vote down an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer, downvoted-questions

I've voted down on a very wrong answer, it was syntax wise and logical wise wrong!
still it was accepted by the user who posted the question.

But this cost me reputation down!

Is this an error of some kind ?

Comment: You always lose rep for voting down answers; however, you dont when you vote down questions.

Comment: Downvoting answers cost you 1 rep. Downvoting question not.

Comment: @Stijn, I know how reputation works, but it seems that by chance i've never downvoted an answer before, so I was a little surprised when I lost 1 reputation point on the question. I assumed it is related to the accepted answers only

Comment: @simsim The duplicate explains in detail which actions cause you to gain or lose reputation.

Comment: hmm, makes sense, if thats the case, logically, I should lose more points on the accepted answer vote down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You lose 1 reputation whenever you cast a downvote on an answer. It's universal, and not an error. This is, among other reasons, to encourage you to consider whether you really want to downvote something.

(Downvoting a question on the other hand costs nothing.)

Comment: And, ummm here is a +1 because I don't want to loose a rep -_- *YAWN*

Comment: **Universal** (adj) : of, affecting, or done by all people or things in the world *or in a particular group* ;)